# How can I locate dom element with relative xpath for selenium python bindings?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**Problem**

1. Find the entity that includes some text. (This is done.)
2. Find the entity next to 1. (This I cannot locate)

Note: I cannot use regular locate element by id, name, class because entity 1 will change for other pages.

**HTML code**

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span tabindex="-1"><label for="value:1:1:1">companyID</label></span>
        <input type="hidden" value="companyID" id="fieldName:1:1:1" name="fieldName:1:1:1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="operand:1:1:1">
          <option selected="" value="EQ">equals</option>
          <option value="LK">matches</option>
          <option value="UL">not matches</option>
          <option value="NE">not equal to</option>
          <option value="GT">greater than</option>
          <option value="GE">greater than or equals</option>
          <option value="LT">less than</option>
          <option value="LE">less than or equals</option>
          <option value="RG">between</option>
          <option value="NR">not between</option>
          <option value="CT">contains</option>
          <option value="NC">not containing</option>
          <option value="BW">begins with</option>
          <option value="EW">ends with</option>
          <option value="DNBW">does not begin with</option>
          <option value="DNEW">does not end with</option>
          <option value="SAID">sounds like</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="text" frequencydropfieldname="value:1:1:1" value="123" size="20" id="value:1:1:1" name="value:1:1:1">
        <input type="hidden" value="none" id="sort:1:1:1" name="sort:1:1:1">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span tabindex="-1"><label for="value:2:1:1">componentID</label></span>
        <input type="hidden" value="componentID" id="fieldName:2:1:1" name="fieldName:2:1:1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="operand:2:1:1">
          <option selected="" value="EQ">equals</option>
          <option value="LK">matches</option>
          <option value="UL">not matches</option>
          <option value="NE">not equal to</option>
          <option value="GT">greater than</option>
          <option value="GE">greater than or equals</option>
          <option value="LT">less than</option>
          <option value="LE">less than or equals</option>
          <option value="RG">between</option>
          <option value="NR">not between</option>
          <option value="CT">contains</option>
          <option value="NC">not containing</option>
          <option value="BW">begins with</option>
          <option value="EW">ends with</option>
          <option value="DNBW">does not begin with</option>
          <option value="DNEW">does not end with</option>
          <option value="SAID">sounds like</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="text" frequencydropfieldname="value:2:1:1" value="ZZ" size="20" id="value:2:1:1" name="value:2:1:1">
        <input type="hidden" value="none" id="sort:2:1:1" name="sort:2:1:1">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

**Python Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('file:///C:/Users/gmunteanu/Desktop/test_table.html')
time.sleep(2)
print driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'companyID')]/td[3]/input[1]")
```

Answer (score 1):

For "next to" there is the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) notation:

```
//span[contains(label, 'companyID')]/following-sibling::input
```

Also, could not you just get the `input` by `value` attribute?

```
//input[@value = 'companyID']
```

<sub>*Assuming you are aiming for that hidden `input` element.</sub>

Comment: thanks for quick reply. Because the html is rather intricate I';d rather use some html pseudocode. Thus: <label> [This I can locate]
<input hidden><selectbox>
<input type text> [This 'input type text' I want to locate in order to write some data]. I will keep investigating ...